# if we have 2 category group name, how to put Category Groups name on top and one on bottom?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTFMp.png)I have in my example 2 category groups, one is the 'username' more granular and the other one is 'date of week'. I would like to have 'username' at the bottom of the bar graph and 'date of week' on top of bar graph.

Can anyone help me achieving this?

Regards,

I have searched Google but no help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q12LD.png)

Answer (score 0):

double click on the chart to bring chart data dialog box, in category groups place username at the top and DOW underneath.

Comment: I think I have not put clearly what I need,

If we divide the canvas in three part then 

top part I would like to have grouping on DOW
Middle Part bar graph
Bottom part grouping on Username.